# Phrase as ship name: With or without article?

Tags: articles, noms-propres, transports

The [names of French ships](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_navires_de_la_Marine_nationale_fran%C3%A7aise) include an article, if the name is an adjective (e.g. *La Glorieuse*), otherwise they have no article (e.g. *Capricorne*). There are a few exceptions such as *La Motte-Picquet*, where the article is part of a personal name, or *L'Aigle*, where it is part of a place name, after which the boat is named.

So if I name a ship "lumière", I think it would be called *Lumière*. But what if the name was something like "lumière dans les ténèbres"? Would it be *La Lumière dans les Ténèbres* or *Lumière dans les Ténèbres*?

---

With name I mean the name as given for example on the hull of the ship. With article:

[image]

Without article:

[image]

Phrase:

[image]

Comment: [Here](http://www.slate.fr/story/42459/comment-nom-bateau), under "Usages et superstitions", it is said that *usually*, ship names should not have articles, except before an adjective (hence "le terrible", but "lumière dans...). It is also said that there is no actual rule, just a common practice, and that there are exceptions. Maybe your question is best suited for http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/ since it isn't really about French language

Comment: @MorganFR: I don't think the superstitions would be the same in any other language. I think this has a place here :) Not sure if people upvoted your comment for the on-topicness issue or for the answer embedded, but maybe you should post an answer in case it's the latter ^^

Comment: I upvoted for the answerness of the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://troisponts.net/2015/09/29/lusage-de-larticle-devant-les-noms-des-navires/) rather detailed article on the matter (in French) could help solve your issue.

The first paragraphs state that although the article used to be a part of the name (*le Soleil-Royal*, *le Redoutable*...), it has not been the case since the middle of the 19th century. The usage described in [the article](http://www.slate.fr/story/42459/comment-nom-bateau) cited by MorganFR corroborates this, with a few exceptions (when the name is also an adjective, or the exceptions that you mentionned yourself).

In your case, I think that the most correct (or usual) way would be to write your ship's name as *Lumière dans les ténèbres*.

There are two last questions to solve. The first one is whether to capitalize the *T* of *ténèbres* ; I would argue against it because of the [rules governing title capitalization](http://sites.univ-lyon2.fr/lettres/zdoc-varia/MajusculesInBiblio.pdf) (though I am not sure that they also apply to ships' names). The second one is: when talking about your ship, should you talk about *la Lumière dans les ténèbres* or about *le Lumière dans les ténèbres*? The first link I posted is all about that very issue; the conclusion is reaches is that usage always uses the masculine *le* for cargo ships and liners (*le France*, etc.), but uses the ship's name's gender for military ships (*la Jeanne d'Arc*, etc.), so it depends on your situation. For a small boat belonging to an individual, I'd probably say *la Lumière*, but I would'nt know for sure.